# Passing values between objects rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get the value of `first_name` from `@message` and pass it as value of `@insert message` params.

something like `(:message => @message.first_name + 'Your request was submitted')` but I get an error when I use this code, undefined method `first_name' for #Friend::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000000020be468

```
@message = Friend.joins(user: :message).select("user.first_name, user.last_name").where(user_id: 1)

@insert = Person.new(:message => 'Your request was submitted')
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Nithin undefined method `first_name' for #<Friend::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000000020be468>

Comment: try `users.first_name, users.last_name` within select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@message = Friend.joins(user: :message).select("users.first_name as first_name, users.last_name as last_name").where(user_id: 1) 
@insert = Person.new(:message => "#{@message.first.first_name} Your request was submitted")
```